# Como agregar ceros a la izquierda a un JTextfied (atributo tipo string)

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo una serie de códigos que contienen números enteros positivos que quiero imprimir haciendo que ocupen el mismo espacio.

Por ejemplo dado:

> j1
>
> j23
>
> j777

Me gustaría que tuvieran ceros a la izquierda y salieran cadenas del tipo:

> j0001
>
> j0023
>
> j0777

Cabe destacar que la **j** es estática me interesa rellenar los espacios entre los numeros y la letras.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
//Letra a convertir
String letra = "j777";
//Se divide por la letra deseada "j"
String[] letras = letra.split("j");
//Se declara el formato al que se desea convertir
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0000");
//Se aplica el formato a la segunda parte del arreglo y se concatena la 'j'
String letraFin = "j"+format.format(Integer.valueOf(letras[1]));
//Se imprime el resultado de la conversión
System.out.println("Formato final: "+ letraFin);
```

Salida en consola:

> Formato final: j0777